# Add a column of differences to tables of summary statistics in Stata

Tags: group-by, stata, tabular

If I make a two way summary statistics table in Stata using `table`, can I add another column that is the *difference* of two other columns?

Say that I have three variables (`a, b, c`). I generate quintiles on `a` and `b` then generate a two-way table of means of `c` in each quintile-quintile intersection. I would like to generate a sixth column that is the difference of mean `c` between the top and bottom quintiles of `b` for each quintile of `a`.

I can generate the table of mean `c` for each quintile-quintile intersection, but I can't figure out the difference column.

```
* generate data
clear
set obs 2000
generate a = rnormal()
generate b = rnormal()
generate c = rnormal()

* generate quantiles for for a and b
xtile a_q = a, nquantiles(5)
xtile b_q = b, nquantiles(5)

* calculate the means of each quintile intersection
table a_q b_q, c(mean c)

* if I want the top and bottom b quantiles
table a_q b_q if b_q == 1 | b_q == 5, c(mean c)
```

---

**Update**: Here's an example of what I would like to do.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `collapse` command you can create customized tables like the one you have in mind.

```
preserve
collapse (mean) c, by(a_q b_q)
keep if inlist(b_q, 1, 5)
reshape wide c, i(a_q) j(b_q)
gen c5_c1 = c5 - c1
set obs `=_N + 1'
replace c1 = c1[`=_N - 1'] - c1[1] if mi(a_q)
replace c5 = c5[`=_N - 1'] - c5[1] if mi(a_q)
replace c5_c1 = c5_c1[`=_N - 1'] - c5_c1[1] if mi(a_q)
list, sep(0) noobs
restore
```

Then you should obtain something like this in your output:

```
  +-----------------------------------------+
  | a_q          c1          c5       c5_c1 |
  |-----------------------------------------|
  |   1    .2092651    .1837719   -.0254932 |
  |   2    .0256483   -.0118134   -.0374617 |
  |   3     .022957    .0586441    .0356871 |
  |   4    .0431809    .0876745    .0444935 |
  |   5   -.0859874    .0199202    .1059076 |
  |   .   -.2952525   -.1638517    .1314008 |
  +-----------------------------------------+
```

If you are not very familiar with Stata, the following help pages might be useful in understanding the code

```
help _variables
help subscripting
```

Comment: Thanks! I realized I can also make the main part of the table with dummies, `regress`, `eststo`, and `esttab`... but I need to think some more on how to generate the margins.

Comment: If you intend to use `regress`, you can work directly with the results that the command leaves behind. The coefficients estimated by `regress` are stored in a matrix called `e(b)`. Using matrix commands (see `help matrix`), you can manipulate these results. I believe it is more cumbersome, and less general. Note that, unlike `regress`, the `collapse` approach allows you to produce statistics other than the mean.

Comment: Instead of subscripts it may be easier to use lag operators. `tsset` the quantile variable to be "time" and then `gen x = y - L5.y`  or simply `gen x = s5.y`   See `help varlist` for details.